# how to add two differents style's jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

have my page and two grid here...the first grid have this style for the column header

```
<style type="text/css">
 .ui-jqgrid table.ui-jqgrid-htable {
     height:60px;
 }
 </style>
```

This is in table1, and in table2 have my other grid but without style

when load the page, the second grid get the style for the first grid and the column header size is 60

what is the problem?

pd: sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS style which you use are applied on both grids because you use *classes* `ui-jqgrid` and `ui-jqgrid-htable` in the CSS rule. The element with the classes exist in both grids. If you want apply some CSS settings on one grid only you can use for example ids. If two grids which you use have ids `table1` and `table2` for example (you use `<table id="table1"></table>` for the first grid and `<table id="table2"></table>` for the second one) then the outer div created by jqGrid (which have `ui-jqgrid` class) will have id="gbox_table1" and id="gbox_table2" (the id of outer div will be build based on the table id by adding the prefix "gbox_"). So is you need to apply `height:60px` only for the first grid (with id="table1") then you should change the CSS rule to

```css
#gbox_table1 table.ui-jqgrid-htable {
    height:60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<style>` elements are supposed to be added in the `<head>` element of an HTML document, and the style applies to the whole document. If the style type is CSS, then the content of the `<style>` is interpreted according to the pattern matching rules of CSS. In your case, if height will be applied to all `<table>` element that has the `ui-jqgrid-htable` class, and it a child of any element type with the class `ui-jqgrid`.

If you want a style to be applied to only one element and its children, use a `style` attribute instead of a `<style>` element.