# How to redice the width of a jqGrid filter toolbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

My grid has only one column, therefore the search toolba very wide (as long as the whole page).  I added a css  element to reduce the width:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>input,
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>select
{
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This is my code:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
          href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
    <!--   to remove the vertical scroll bar in column header in chrome -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-jqgrid-hdiv { overflow-y: hidden; },    
        .ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>input,
        .ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>select
        {
            display: block;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        } 

    </style>          

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Shipment Visibility</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery().ready(function () {
            var grid = jQuery("#shipment_grid");
            var mainGridPrefix = "s_";
            grid.jqGrid({
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getTruckShipmentJSONAction?truckId=' + <c:out value="${truckId}" />,
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'GET',
                loadonce: true,
                colNames: ['Lead Tracking #'],
                colModel: [
                    {name: 'trackingNr', width: 100}
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                height: "auto",
                width: 750,
                idPrefix: mainGridPrefix,
                autoheight: true,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: jQuery('#shipment_grid_pager'),
                sortname: 'trackingNr',
                sortorder: "desc",
                jsonReader: {
                    root: "records",
                    page: "page",
                    repeatitems: false
                },
                viewrecords: true,
                altRows: false,
                gridview: true,
                multiselect:true,
                hidegrid: false,
                shrinkToFit: true,
                forceFit: true,
                idPrefix: mainGridPrefix,
                caption: "Shipments Overview",
                subGrid: true,
                beforeProcessing: function(data) {  
                //Customise the record text at the right hand side of the pagination
                grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {recordtext: "{2} Shipment(s) Found. Displaying {0} to {1}"});

                    var rows = data.records, l = rows.length, i, item, subgrids = {};
                    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                        item = rows[i];
                        if (item.shipUnitView) {
                            subgrids[item.id] = item.shipUnitView;
                        }
                    }
                    data.userdata = subgrids;

                },              
                subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
                    var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
                        pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId),
                        subgrids = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData");

                    $subgrid.appendTo("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
                    $subgrid.jqGrid({
                        datatype: "local",
                        data: subgrids[pureRowId],
                        colNames: ['Ship Type (Pallet / Carton)', 'Ship Unit (Pallet ID / Cone #)', 'Total Cartons'],
                        colModel: [
                            { name: "shipUnitType"},
                            { name: "reference", sorttype: "integer" },
                         { name: "totalOfCartons", sorttype: "integer" }
                        ],
                        cmTemplate: { align: "center" },
                        sortname: "reference",
                        sortorder: "desc",
                        height: "100%",
                        rowNum: 10,
                        autowidth: true,
                        autoencode: true,
                        gridview: true,
                        idPrefix: rowId + "_"
                    });
                }
            }).navGrid('#shipment_grid_pager', {edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true})
            .jqGrid("setLabel", "trackingNr", "", {"text-align": "left"}); //align 'Lead Tracking #' column header  to the left;

            grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autoSearch: true});
            //var $search_toolbar = $("tr.ui-search-toolbar", grid[0].grid.hDiv);
            //$search_toolbar.width(50);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="shipment_grid"></table>
<div id="shipment_grid_pager"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it does not work. See my jsfiddle here: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njiterry/97j49Lot/3/). 
How can I reduce the width of the filter tooolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem you can add `searchoptions.attr` property with additional attributes in the column where you need to change options of the searching field. For example

```js
searchoptions: { attr: {size:18, maxlength: 18, style: "width:130px;margin-top:1px;"}
```

See updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/97j49Lot/7/.

I would recommend you additionally to add CSS rule

```css
/* to remove "clear" ("x") part in IE */
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-input>input::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

to have the same width of input box in IE10 and higher .

**UPDATED**: To use "clear" functionality of jqGrid one can use `searchoptions.clearSearch` option. In combination with setting `width` style on the input box one can use

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-clear { width: 100%; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-clear a { float: left; }
```

and

```js
searchoptions: {
    clearSearch: true,
    attr: { size:18, maxlength: 18, style: "width:130px;margin-top:1px;" }
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/97j49Lot/8/

Comment: I love the "clear" ("x") functionality. It is now very far from the search box. I want to keep it beside the search box.  How can I do that?

Comment: @Terry: See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: It works, thanks. This grid is actually displayed when I click on a row in a bigger main grid, but I have the following problem: when I double click on a row in the main grid, the new grid opens with the correctly aligned clearSearch "x" but the filter boxes in bigger grid shrink completely because the css .ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-clear { width: 100%; } in the smaller grid overides that of the main grid. How can make sure that this css only affects the smaller grid?

Comment: @Terry: Sorry, but can you describe the testcase on http://jsfiddle.net/97j49Lot/8/ for example to reproduce the problem. The double click on a row do nothing. Why the new grid could be opened? Probably you mean *another code* which you use currently. In the case you should open new question and describe clear and detailed (if it's possible, with the test case: steps to reproduce the problem).

Comment: My question is, I have two grids (parent and child grid). this is not a grid and subgrid relationship; the two grids are defined in two <table>...</table> tags. How can I ensure that the css code: .ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-clear { width: 100%; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-search-table .ui-search-clear a { float: left; } is only applied to one of the grids

Comment: I solved the issue  by using   #gbox_shipment_grid table.ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-clear { width: 100%; }
  #gbox_shipment_grid table.ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-clear a { float: left; }. Found the solution from your answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885223/how-to-add-two-differents-styles-jqgrid. Many thanks for your constant help.

Comment: @Terry: You are welcome! Usage of id selector in the CSS rules seems me the most easy way too. Alternatively you can use `dataInit` of `searchoptions` to set all required styles of elements near of the searching element. In the case you will can set inline styles instead of usage CSS rules.

Comment: That is interesting. Can you tell me how I can set inline styles in dataInit of searchoptions as a replacement of  #gbox_shipment_grid table.ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-clear { width: 100%; } #gbox_shipment_grid table.ui-jqgrid-htable .ui-search-clear a { float: left; }

Comment: @Terry: It's very easy. Look at the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/97j49Lot/9/. If needed you can include such `searchoptions.dataInit` in *one grid* only.